# Selecting raster cells by multiband values in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator

I have a raster of roads saved from a WMS, this a multiband raster.
Its red(main) an grey(back) roads.

When using the raster calculator I can select most of the red road by using: `Band@1 > 200`

But what expression is to be used to select the grey road?

At all grey colours, the 3 bands have the same value. My guess was that this would work, but it did not: `Band@1 = Band@2 = Band@3`.

I have tried a couple of other variants, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a sample of RGB raster of 4 cells:

- Upper left cell: Light grey (150, 150, 150)
- Lower left cell: Dark grey (100, 100, 100)
- Upper right cell: Red (250, 0, 0)
- Lower right cell: Blue (0, 0, 250)

[image]

Equation to the Raster calculator to create the filter:

```
( "Band@1" - "Band@2" = 0) * ( "Band@2" - "Band@3" = 0 ) = 1
```

(This also works without `= 1` .)

The filter returns 1 for R,G,B band (or @1, @2, @3 as in Raster calculator) have the same value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`band0 = band1 = band2` won't work because it will be processed from one side to another e.g `(band0 = band1) = band2` and the results of `(band0 = band1)` will be true or false and consequently not equal to `band2`.

Instead: `(band0 = band1) AND (band1 = band2)` should work